# I am stumped by a seemingly simple active_record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 tables.  One contains genealogy data (families), the other contains people data.
I want to create an association so that I can access the people data based on pointers from the genealogy table.  For instance:

```
    <% @families.each do |family| %>
...
    <td> <%= family.father.first_name %></td>
```

Here is the conroller code:

```
  def index
      @families = Family.joins(:people)
  end
```

Here are the 2 schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE "people" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name_prefix" varchar, "first_name" varchar, "middle_name" varchar, "last_name" varchar, "name_suffix" varchar, "date_of_birth" varchar, "date_of_death" varchar, "gender" varchar, "notes" varchar, "sync_outlook" varchar, "sync_phone" varchar, "flags" varchar, "created_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL, "place_of_birth" varchar, "aliases" varchar);

CREATE TABLE "families" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "fam_notes" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "fam_fatherid" integer DEFAULT NULL, "fam_motherid" integer DEFAULT NULL, "fam_weddingdate" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "fam_weddingplace" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "created_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime(6) NOT NULL);
```

Here is the model code:

```
class Family < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :childlinks, foreign_key: "child_family"
    has_many :people, through: :childlinks

    #has_one :father, through: :families, source: "fam_fatherid"
    has_one :father, foreign_key: "fam_fatherid"
    has_one :person, through: :father
end
```

When I put a break in the web page, @families exists, but the associated father does not.

```
>> @families[0].father
NameError: uninitialized constant Family::Father
```

I have tried every combination of has_one, through, foreign_key, source, etc. that I can think of, and nothing has produced a 'family' object with a linked (or associated) 'father' object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check [the associations guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). You probably should have `belongs_to :father, foreign_key: "fam_fatherid", class_name: 'Person'`

Comment: Are you working with a legacy table that can't be fixed or are you open to a more convential solution?

Comment: Hi @max, if you are referring to :father as the table that needs to be fixed, it is not a table.  I'm trying to instantiate a person object under each family named :father so that I can access it for each family as family[index].father.first_name.  In other words, the sql it produces should be something like : select first_name from person where person.id=fam_fatherid.  Does that make more sense?  Am I way off-base using an association for this?

Comment: @AbM, The association you suggested did the trick.  I had missed your reply because there were 2 at the same time.  I learned a lot from Max's reply, but for the time being, I think I will retain the design schema that I currently have because it seems to be working for my needs, and I have several scaffolds built around it.  I don't see a button to close out the question as answered,

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume here that we are just modeling biological assocations and not the whole can of worms that is the real world and I'm going to stick to the Rails conventions instead of unfuddling your schema.

If you want to put the mother/father combo as different columns on one table this is how you would do it:

```
class CreateFamilies < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :families do |t|
      t.belongs_to :father, 
        null: false, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: :persons }
      t.belongs_to :mother, 
        null: false, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: :persons }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Family < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :father, 
    class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :mother, 
    class_name: 'Person'
  has_many :children, 
    class_name: 'Person',
    inverse_of: :family
end
```

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord 
  # @todo add a family_id foreign key column to persons
  # this is a persons link to their parents
  # Must be nullable to avoid a chicken-vs-egg scenario
  belongs_to :family, 
    optional: true,
    inverse_of: :children
  has_one :father, through: :family
  has_one :mother, through: :family
end
```

Note that you don't actually need a join table between children and the family as the relationshop is one to many and not many to many. Each child can only belong to one set of parents. You also need to use `belongs_to` when the foreign key is on *this* models table.

So far its pretty simple. However once you start adding relations to a persons children it gets crazy:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord 
  # this is a persons link to their parents
  # Must be nullable to avoid a chicken-vs-egg scenario
  belongs_to :family, 
    optional: true,
    inverse_of: :children

  has_one :father, through: :family
  has_one :mother, through: :family

  has_many :maternal_families,
    class_name: 'Family',
    foreign_key: :mother_id

  has_many :maternal_children,
    through: :maternal_families,
    source: :children

  has_many :paternal_families,
    class_name: 'Family',
    foreign_key: :father_id

  has_many :paternal_children,
    through: :paternal_families,
    source: :children
end
```

The reason you need so many assocations is that each `has_many` assocation must point to a single foreign key in ActiveRecord.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to answer in such detail.  It seems that I am not as far ahead in my understanding of Rails as I thought.  Coming from a procedural language with a heirarchical database, I will have to implement the ideas you presented and try to get the pieces to fit together in my head.  One reason for the table design I chose is that my daughter is adopted, so right off the bat, she fits into 2 separate family units.  I just need to spend some more time studying Rails.  I tried to upvote, but don't have enough rep.  Will return to your post when I do. Again, thank you.  Jere

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was hinting at with the first paragraph. It's not a great fit for the complexity of real life. For example my half brother and I wouldn't be in the same family. I would really go with a model where you use one row per child/parent relationship with just a parent_id and child_id. That lets you build a node graph in any number of ways.